# How to build hidden features in shell scripting, which are activated by user input using flags?

Tags: shell-script

I want to build an extra feature in my script, which only runs if the user tells it to.

E.g. I have the program `tree.sh` which takes a gene input. E.g.

```
./tree.sh AIFM1
```

But I want to have an extra feature that visualises the gene.

I want to use flags to trigger the extra features in the shell script. I found this in the link: https://jonalmeida.com/posts/2013/05/26/different-ways-to-implement-flags-in-bash/. I would like to use flags, however the first argument is to search for something in a website (which could pretty much be anything). Meaning I need the use of cases, but one of the cases needs to account for anything else that wasn't specified in the cases. (e.g. like an else statement).
How do I resolve this issue, without importing any special packages?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue.
when using the case statement, each case is characterised by `* )` For a case representing any input that wasn't determined by other cases all you need is just `* )` without any specified condition before it.